# Is this the correct way to use "jusqu'à" ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

Here is what I have written:

> On doit étudier toutes les matières **jusqu'à partir de la troisième**. Ensuite, on peut choisir entre les sciences économiques et la technologie, mais c'est obligatoire d'étudier les maths, les sciences, la géographie et l'anglais.

Am I using the expression "jusqu'à" correctly?

Comment: *Jusqu'à* is nearly always followed by a noun, and you're following it with a verb. So I don't think that's quite right! Grammatically you probably want *jusqu'au début de la troisième,* although a native speaker should check my math, so to speak, since I'm not sure if it's idiomatic for this sentence.

Comment: *Jusqu'à quitter la troisième* ? *Partir* is somehow synonymous with *quitter* but in this context it will mislead your reader...

Comment: As a native speaker, I would agree with @Aerovistae for "Jusqu'au début de la troisième"

Comment: Why not just say this is not grammatical in French? It is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually one says "jusqu'à ..." (until) or "à partir de ..." (starting from). I think "jusqu'à partir de la troisième" might be grammatically correct in theory, meaning "until one leaves *la troisième*" but a native speaker would never say that as it is ambiguous.

If you mean "until leaving", I'd say (with increasing preference) *jusqu'à la fin de la troisième*, *jusqu'au collège*, *jusqu'en troisième*, *jusqu'à la fin du collège*.

While I'm at it, a few corrections: *on peut entre* should probably be *on peut choisir entre*, and *obligatoire étudier* should be *obligatoire d'étudier*. Again by the way, in current French *collège* one has *Technologie* as a mandatory class, and in the *lycée* one can choose between *sciences économiques* and several other subjects, but not *Technologie* which does not exist in the *lycée général*, so your last sentence is not correct with regard to current conditions in France.

Source: I am not *quite* a native speaker but I do have one kid in *lycée* and another in *collège*.

Comment: "jusqu'à partir de" can't be correct. "à partir" always means "starting from", if you want to say "until one leaves" you could use the very old-fashioned "jusqu'au partir de (la troisième)" or the more common "jusqu'à ce qu'on/qu'il quitte (la troisième)"

Comment: @AnneAunyme I was estimating that *jusqu'à*, normally followed by a noun, can be followed by an infinitive verb standing in for a noun, like in *il est allé jusqu'à quitter son emploi*, *jusqu'à venir*, etc., and that therefore the construct might be correct on a purely theoretical grammatical level. Of course we agree that *jusqu'à partir* should absolutely not be used. Grammatical or not, *peu importe*, it is basically incomprehensible.

Comment: You are right, I did not think about this construction !

Comment: As a native speaker (from Belgium, not France), I would not say "jusqu'à quitter la troisième".

Comment: @GillesV. I agree that it sounds bizarre. It was already the expression I preferred least, but I've deleted it from my answer. All the examples I can think of of *Il (X, v conjugué) jusqu'à (Y, v à l'infinitif)* imply a causal relationship where repeating X sooner or later entails Y, instead of Y just happening and causing X to stop . . . maybe because Y even though infinitive has an implied subject which is the same as X. With *Il (X) jusqu'à ce que* one can have a different subject in the subordinate clause: *Il joua jusqu'à ce qu'on l'appelle*. Am I going too far . . . probably :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is quite good but I want to make something precise.

You can just say "jusqu'à la troisième". This will mean "until the end of *la troisième*"

I would say like this :

"On doit étudier toutes les mati**è**res jusqu'à la troisième. Ensuite, on peut choisir entre les sciences économiques et la technologie, mais c'est obligatoire **d'** étudier les maths, les sciences, la géographie et l'anglais. "

Comment: I improved my answer but I still prefer specifying *la fin de*. Good catch on *matiéres*, I do recommend using a basic spell-checker for such things!